# Why Assert.AreEqual has only overloads for double and object

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to compare ints, booleans, strings and others. Out of curiosity, why does Assert.AreEqual supports doubles but not other types explicitly?

Should I do:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var areEqual = a == b;
Assert.IsTrue(areEqual);
```

instead of:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
```

Edit for clarification: The question is why this method don't support other types explicitly  and does so only for double types.

Edit 2 for more clarification: This question is about curiosity, I have no issues to solve.

Comment: And what problem are you having with the second snippet?  In what way does it fail to behave as you want it to?

Comment: Not much as it fails, rather than an unpexpected boxing moment, since it uses de (object, object) overload I was wondering why there's no overload for other types rather than just double.

Comment: As I asked before, how, *specifically* does it fail to behave as you expect?  Saying, "it fails" is unhelpful.

Comment: I didn't say it fails, it doesn't, it works. As I said, it was unexpected for me that this method does boxing for any type other than double.

Comment: If you only care about boxing, then you should ask that, instead of asking why it doesn't support types that work just fine.  It *does* support them, that's why they work.  Do you have some performance problem as a result of the boxing?  Is it impeding your ability to properly run your tests?

Comment: Sorry for not making this more clearer. I have no issues, no problems, no test fails, no performance issues. I'm just curious as to why this is the way it is, it seemed odd to me and wanted to know if someone had any insight on the matter.

Comment: If you want to know why the designer designed it that way then *ask them* why they designed it that way, rather than asking people who *didn't* design it why someone else choose to do what they did.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your time and effort to help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to look at the exact method signatures:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(double expected, double actual, double tolerance);
Assert.AreEqual(object expected, object actual);
```

As you can see, there is some "tolerance" concept that apparently only applies when comparing `double` types. [The documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.AreEqual.html) actually addresses this point directly:

> Values of type float and double are compared using an additional argument that indicates a tolerance within which they will be considered as equal.

So the overload is to deal with precision issues when comparing floating point values. This is a very well-documented problem online. For example, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=net-5.0) from Microsoft:

> two apparently equivalent values can be unequal due to the differing precision of the two values [... ] Rather than comparing for equality, one technique involves defining an acceptable relative margin of difference between two values (such as .001% of one of the values)

To compare two `double` values, you should do something like this:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1, 0.3, 0.00000001);
```

Comment: Thanks for the links! That makes so much sense.